# Compute a ratio of count and geomean of certain other counts in the same table

Tags: matrix, powerbi

[image: Excel Table]

My Power BI table has a column of 'Parts' of 'Type' A and B, each with a certain 'Count'. I want to be able to compute in DAX, for each row of Type A Part, a ratio of its Count and the geomean of all Counts of Type B. The image above shows the desired computation. Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thank you.

In my matrix visual, I have 'Parts' in the 'Rows' field. The matrix displays the type and count for each part. The geomean of type B is getting computed for each type B row instead of all of type B parts. I have been experimenting with ways to make the geomean computation ignore the 'Rows' field, but without success.